# When specifying the universal property that defines $V \otimes W$, what category are we working in?

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products

What category does $V \otimes W$ satisfy its universal property in? I'm having a hard time figuring out what the arrows in the category in question are supposed to be. I don't think it's just the category of vector spaces with arrows being linear maps because bilinear maps are not linear maps and I'm not sure what collection of arrows contains bilinear and linear maps without simply containing all functions between vector spaces.

All vector spaces in this question are over a fixed field $F$.

---

The universal property of definition of the tensor product is [given here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property).

I've reproduced a similar diagram [to this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Another_universal_tensor_prod.svg) below, but added in an extra identity arrow from $Z$ because I can't figure out how to draw a diagonal arrow, also the arrow from $V \otimes W$ to $Z$ should be dashed. I also changed the notation for $h'$ to use a prime instead of a superscript tilde.

In the diagram below, $h$ is bilinear, $\varphi$ is bilinear, and $h'$ is linear. Additionally $h'$ is uniquely determined.

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V \times W @>{\varphi}>> V \otimes W\\
@V{h}VV @VV{h'}V \\
Z @>{\text{id}}>> Z
\end{CD}
$$

I don't understand which category specifically this diagram is in.

$V$, $W$, $V \times W$, $Z$ and $V \otimes W$ are all vector spaces. Additionally, $h$ and $\varphi$ are bilinear, but $h'$ is linear, so it's not clear to me what the collection of arrows as a whole should be.

---

What follows is my understanding of how to build $V \otimes W$ by imposing equalities on the free vector space over $V \times W$.

This is my attempt to understand how the tensor product of vector spaces is defined *using different machinery*.

---

The concrete construction for the tensor product makes intuitive sense and I think I understand the intuition for why a bilinear map from $V \times W$ to an arbitrary $Z$ would necessarily be completely determined by what it does to the basis of $V \otimes W$. I don't have a proof of this fact at the moment though.

Here's my understanding of how to produce a specific concrete vector space given two vector spaces.

I'll use ${v \choose w}$ to nonstandardly denote the formal tensor product of $v$ and $w$, which I'm thinking of as a fancy kind of ordered pair.

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces. I will now define $T$, the tensor product of $V$ and $W$.

Let $T^1$ be defined as $\{ {v \choose w} \mathop| v \in V \land w \in W \} $.

Let $T^2$ be the set of formal finite linear combinations of elements of $T_1$, with coefficients taken from $F$, our fixed field of scalars.

Let $T^3$ be defined by taking $T^2$ and modding out by the congruence relation $\simeq$.

Let $\simeq$ be the congruence relation generated by $(\simeq_0)$ and respecting the operations $+$ and scalar multiplication by $k$. $(\simeq_0)$ is defined below.

$$ {v_1 \choose w} + {v_2 \choose w} \;(\simeq_0)\; {v_1 + v_2 \choose w} $$
$$ {v \choose w_1} + {v \choose w_2} \;(\simeq_0)\; {v \choose w_1 + w_2} $$
$$ (k){v \choose w} \;(\simeq_0)\; {kv \choose w} $$
$$ (k){v \choose w} \;(\simeq_0)\; {v \choose kw} $$

Let $T$ be equal to $T^3$.

Comment: $V \otimes W$ has a universal property in the category of vector spaces, in the sense that linear maps out of $V \otimes W$ can be defined in terms of some other construction. This other construction is not defined solely in terms of the category of vector spaces but that is beside the point.

Comment: @ZhenLin Is that universal property different from the one in commutative diagram cited in the question? I'm having trouble understanding how to interpret it, specifically, given that $V \times W$ isn't a vector space. Their commutative diagram makes sense though, on a purely intuitive level, as a "criterion that a candidate for $V \otimes W$ must fulfill in order to be the tensor product".

Comment: The diagram you ask about commutes in sets. If you want to fit this into a general categorical story, it can be presented as representability. The functor BiLin(V,W;_) from the category of vector spaces to sets is representable.

Comment: I'm planning to write an answer expanding on Nex's comment, but first some feedback on your post: (1) Why do you say $V\times W$ is not a vector space? We're not using its vector space structure here (instead considering it as the domain of a bilinear map). But it certainly is a vector space. (2) Why do you write "Let $V'$ be a vector space up to isomorphism with concrete model $V$"? This seems like unnecessary conceptual baggage, and $V'$ does not appear again in your discussion.

Comment: (3) Your definition of $T_2$ as "finite sequences taken with elements taken from $T_1$" doesn't do what you want. There's nothing in your construction that makes the vector space axioms hold; e.g., the way you've defined it, $+$ is not commutative. You wrote "$ka = ka$ for $e$ in $a$". I guess you meant "$ka = ke$ for $e$ in $a$", but even so I don't understand how this specifies a finite sequence of elements of $T_1$. If $e$ is in $T_1$, what is $ke$? What you're trying to do here is to make $T_2$ the free vector space with basis $T_1$. Its elements should be finite *linear combinations* ...

Comment: of elements of $T_1$: $\sum_{v\in  T_1} c_vv$ where each $c_v$ is a scalar and only finitely many of the $c_v$ are non-zero. (4) It's not enough to take $\simeq$ to be the equivalence relation generated by $\simeq_0$. Instead you need $\simeq$ to be the *congruence* generated by $\simeq_0$. This means that if $v\simeq v'$ and $w\simeq w'$, then we should have $v+w\simeq v'+w'$ and $cv\simeq cv'$ when $c$ is a scalar. Usually this is done by quotienting by the *subspace generated* by all the differences of $\simeq_0$-equivalent elements. (5) There are some typos in the definition of $\simeq_0$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I removed the claim that $V \times W$ is not a vector space. I was trying to work out how to make a coarser structure out of the free vector space over $V \times W$ and forgot about component-wise addition as, uh, addition in $V \times W$. I'm working on fixing the other problems with the post too, but won't change its overall structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "universal property" does not have a universally agreed upon definition, as far as I know. But most universal properties can be understood in terms of representable functors.

Let $C$ be a category. A functor $F\colon C\to \mathsf{Set}$ is *representable* if there is some object $x\in C$ such that $F$ is naturally isomorphic to the Hom  functor $h^x\colon  C\to \mathsf{Set}$, which is defined on objects by $h^x(y) = \mathrm{Hom}(x,y)$ and on arrows by $h^x(f) = f\circ -\colon \mathrm{Hom}(x,y)\to \mathrm{Hom}(x,z)$ for  $f\colon y\to z$.

If $F$ is representable by $x$, then the set $\mathrm{Hom}(x,y)$ is in natural bijection with the set $F(y)$. That is, arrows out of $x$ to $y$ are classified by elements of $F(y)$.

In fact, the situation is even better than that! The identity arrow $\mathrm{id}_x\in \mathrm{Hom}(x,x)$ corresponds to an element $u\in F(x)$, and $u$ is "universal" in the following sense: For every object $y$ in $C$ and every element $a\in F(y)$, there is a unique arrow $f\colon x\to y$ in $C$ such that $F(f)(u) = a$.

The existence of $u\in F(x)$ with  this universal property is equivalent to the statement that $F$ is representable by $x$ - the proof is essentially the proof of the Yoneda lemma. Of course this whole discussion has  a dual version for universal properties in which maps *into* $x$ from $y$ are classified  by  elements of $G(y)$ for  a *contravariant* functor $G$ to $\mathrm{Set}$.

---

Ok, what about tensor products? Fixing vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over a field $k$, there is a functor $B_{V,W}\colon \mathrm{Vect}_k\to \mathrm{Set}$ defined by $B_{V,W}(U) = \{f\colon V\times W\to U\mid f\text{ is bilinear}\}$. If $T\colon U\to U'$ is a morphism of vector spaces (a linear transformation) and $f\colon V\times W\to U$ is bilinear, then $T\circ f\colon V\times W\to U'$ is bilinear. This defines the action of $B_{V,W}$ on morphisms: $B_{V,W}(T)\colon B_{V,W}(U)\to B_{V,W}(U')$ is defined by $B_{V,W}(T)(f) = T\circ f$.

Now what does it mean to say that this functor $B_{V,W}$ is represented by the tensor product $V\otimes W$? By the discussion above, there is a universal $b\in B_{V,W}(V\otimes W)$ such that for any vector space $U$ and any element $f\in B_{V,W}(U)$, there is a unique morphism of vector spaces $\tilde{f}\colon V\otimes W\to U$ such that $f = B_{V,W}(\tilde{f})(b)$. Unpacking, we have a distinguished bilinear map $b\colon V\times W\to V\otimes W$, and for any bilinear map $f\colon V\times W\to U$, there is a unique morphism of vector spaces $\tilde{f}\colon V\otimes W\to U$ such that $f = \tilde{f}\circ b$. This is exactly the familiar universal property of the tensor product.

---

Note that there was no need to consider any categories in the above discussion other than the category $\mathrm{Vect}_k$ of vector spaces over $k$ and the category $\mathrm{Set}$ of sets. To define the functor $B_{V,W}$, we did have to consider composing two different kinds of maps, namely bilinear maps and linear maps. But of course these are special kinds of functions, and we know how to compose functions - to make sense of this, we are *not* required to consider a category where the objects are vector spaces and the arrows include both linear maps and bilinear maps.

Nevertheless, it is reasonable to wonder whether such a category exists. It turns out that the right type of structure to consider here is not a category, but a [multicategory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicategory). Multicategories are generalizations of categories in which every arrow has a finite sequence of objects as its domain. The main motivating example is the multicategory where the objects are vector spaces and the arrows $(V_1,\dots,V_n)\to W$ are the multilinear maps $V_1\times\dots\times V_n\to W$.

In this multicategory, the tensor product $V_1\otimes\dots\otimes V_n$ has the universal property that any arrow $(V_1,\dots,V_n)\to W$ factors uniquely as the canonical arrow $(V_1,\dots,V_n)\to V_1\otimes \dots\otimes V_n$ followed by an arrow $V_1\otimes \dots\otimes V_n\to W$.

Since I know that you (the OP) are interested in logic, I'll mention that other examples of multicategories come from logic. For example, take objects to be sentences and arrows $(P_1,\dots,P_n)\to Q$ to be sequents $P_1,\dots,P_n\vdash Q$ (so there is an arrow $(P_1,\dots,P_n)\to Q$ if and only if $Q$ follows from assumptions $P_1,\dots,P_n$). In classical propositional logic, the conjunction $P_1\land \dots \land P_n$ has the universal property of the tensor product.

Comment: I have two basic questions about the last example. Are the proof-multicategory where I get a distinct arrow for each proof and the truth-multicategory where every homset (multihomset?) is empty or a singleton both valid multicategories? Does conjunction have the universal property of the tensor product only in the latter multicategory or in both?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Right, this is an issue that comes up whenever we want to view proof systems as categories. The idea is to view sentences as objects and proofs as arrows, but to satisfy the axioms of categories (and for logical constructs to satisfy universal  properties) we need to quotient by some equivalence relation on proofs. This even comes up when we want to verify the identity axiom: does composing a proof $P$ of $\varphi\vdash \psi$ with the trivial proof $\text{id}$ of $\psi\vdash \psi$ literally result in the same proof $P$?

Comment: The easiest equivalence relation to quotient by is the trivial one that identifies all proofs of the same sequent. Then we get the provability preorder (viewing a preorder as a category in which every homset is empty or a singleton). In the multicategory case,  I think people call these "multiorders" or maybe "multipreorders".

Comment: But you could also inductively the minimal equivalence relation on proofs that makes everything work. You end up with something that looks like a proof system for proving that two proofs are equal! And this suggests a higher categorical approach where instead of quotienting, you only ask the (multi)category axioms to hold up to isomorphism of arrows etc.

Comment: I will pose this as a proper question when I can, but I was wondering what would happen if you remove the requirement that identity arrows exist in a ... semimulticategory (?) ? So some propositions won't necessarily have a "content-free" proof of themselves given themselves as a premise.